# Add a white border / stroke to Flot Point (jQuery graph)

Tags: jquery, graph, styles, flot

See this graph that positionly.com use: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kz9ksagctf7zpaa/Screenshot%202015-12-18%2010.31.03.png?dl=0

Is it possible to recreate this on a Flot jQuery graph?

Currently I have the following options:

```
    points    : {
        show     : true,
        radius   : 2,
        lineWidth: 3,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fill     : true,
        shadowSize: 0
```

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/07wm4r8ojzhr5js/Screenshot%202015-12-18%2010.32.45.png?dl=0

Any ideas on how to add a border / stroke - or whether this is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with default Flot options. You can define a seperate `fillColor` for the points, but not a seperate border / stroke color.

One workaround for this is to define two data series with the same data:

- The first with the normal `color: red` (or green) which only has the
  line enables
- and the second with `color: white` and `fillColor: red`
  (or green) which has the points enabled.

Result:
[image: example chart]

Code (more in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4phy0k3/)):

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{
    data: sin,
    label: "sin(x)",
    color: 'red',
    points: {
        show: false,
    },
    lines: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 5
    }
}, {
    data: sin,
    color: 'white',
    points: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 2,
        radius: 5,
        fill: true,
        fillColor: 'red'
    },
    lines: {
        show: false
    }
}],
```